# Python method parameter input

Tags: python

I am creating a python activity and I am wondering how setting the parameter of my method as a data type work

my code is:

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, weight: int, energy_add: int, happiness_add: int):
        self.weight = weight # in kg
        self.energy_add = energy_add
        self.happiness_add = happiness_add  


class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_number: int, name: str, weight: float):
        self.student_number = student_number
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight  # in kg

    def eat(self,food = Food(int, int, int)):
        self.weight = food.weight


class EEE111Student(Student):
    energy_level = 50
    happiness_level = 50

    def eat(self,food = Food(int, int, int)):
        print(self.weight)
        self.weight += food.weight
        print(food.weight)
        print(self.weight)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    num_students = int(input("Enter the number of students: "))

    students = []
    for idx in range(num_students):
        # TODO: create new_student here
        new_student = EEE111Student(student_number=idx, name=f"Student{idx}", weight=(50 + (0.5 * (idx -1))) )
        students.append(new_student) 

    food_choises = {
        "papaya"  : Food(weight=0.10, energy_add=10, happiness_add=5),
        "corn": Food(weight=0.20, energy_add=5, happiness_add=6),
    }
    students[0].eat(food = food_choises["papaya"])
    students[0].eat(food = food_choises["corn"])
```

I am grateful that it works because i tried setting the parameter for EEE111's eat method as :

```
def eat(self,food = Food(Food.weight, Food.energy_add, Food.happiness_add)):
        print(self.weight)
        self.weight += food.weight
        print(food.weight)
        print(self.weight)
```

I am wondering if this might be a basic structure for a python code

Comment: `Food.weight`, for example, is not a static property of the class, so what are you expecting  that to be? And no, I don't think `Food(int, int, int)` is valid either ... Why would you want a default parameter here at all?

Comment: My way of thinking was that it will it will pass the values from the food_choices's Food object. I am wondering if this Is a valid code or if I might just be lucky for choosing that parameter for eat.

Comment: Every time you call `Food()`, it creates a new object, so it doesn't pass values from anywhere else, only `food = food_choises["..."]` passes objects from that dictionary

Comment: Since you're never calling `student.eat()` without parameters, then you should just remove `food = ...` from the method definitions and use `food: Food` as the required parameter type

Comment: Thank youuu! 
It was really a great help!
Thank you very much sir!!

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling `eat()` without an parameter, so you don't need a default Food value being passed.

Instead, you can just define the type

```
def eat(self, food: Food)
```